# Gas range top burner - fuel line blocked between valve and burner orifice

Tags: stove, gas-burner

I have a Frigidaire convection oven, model KGSS907SSS00.  The front left burner has a dual mode.  Inner circle on the burner (for igniting and low flame) doesn't get any gas.  Outer circle (high flame) does.  I removed the dual valve and determined both are working fine.  I blew through the gas line connecting to the problem inner burner and determined it is blocked.

I've tried blowing compressed air from both directions and remains blocked.  I tried running a small wire hose-cleaner type of metal brush down from the valve side and it reaches the blockage and can't clear it.  Trying to run the brush from the burner side hasn't worked.  I sprayed solvent and no change.

Removal of the top panel on the stove is complicated by the fact that all the burner bases are secured by very corroded screws. I already sheared one screw even after applying penetrating oil and giving it time to work.  If I have to go the route of removing them I can but am hoping to avoid if I can clean the blockage in place.

Any recommendations on how to clean the line out without removal?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Perhaps a picture or two of the pipes would help get you a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to clear the blockage.  I considered a number of different cleaners to see what I might use.  All of them said don't use on aluminum.  The gas line is aluminum.  I settled on dawn dish detergent in water.  Soaked it overnight from the burner side.  Applied compressed air to the valve side of the gas line and it eventually blew out the obstruction.